# Why is my page still executing?

Tags: php, header

I have a form that posts to a processing script which checks for errors in the post. Depending on the processing it header redirects to another location. This appeared to work but I have just noticed that is still executing stuff after the header.

What is going on?

Comment: Could you please post the code? It would help in tracking down the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Read more here: http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-exit-after-header-redirect.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We will need some code, to see exactly what is going on...

But most likely you sure not using an exit(); or die(); after your header("Location: ...");

e.g.

```
//check your post

if($errors)
{
    header("Location: errors.php"); // bug fixed =D
    exit();

    // this will still be executed if the exit was not there.
}
```

Comment: More explanation I've written here: http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-exit-after-header-redirect.html

Answer (score 4):

Put `die();` after the `header()` function;

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour - calling `header()` won't halt the script immediately. For most other headers (Content-type, ETag, Expires, etc.) you don't **want** it to halt, as those headers relate to the content that's about to follow; in that regard, Location: is slightly unusual.